# Nuxt.js: How to switch color mode?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nuxt.js

I want to switch color mode of my SPA.
And my spa is using nuxt.js.

There are two bootstrap files.
`app.scss`
`app-dark.scss`

nuxt.config.js

```
...

css: [
  '~/plugins/theme/scss/app.scss',
  '~/plugins/theme/scss/app-dark.scss',
],

...
```

I want to switch color mode dynamically using these bootstrap scss files.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can go dark with the plugin [`@nuxtjs/color-mode`](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-dark-with-nuxtjs-color-mode). There you can assign a class (like `.dark-mode` in `app-dark.scss`) that will cover the entire app, and there you can assign a button to update settings.

This plugin saves the preference in cookies and local storage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I use ```app-dark.scss``` with ```@nuxtjs/color-mode```? Without assigning a class additionally.

Comment: Yes, but you have to wrap every variable within `.dark-mode`. For example: `.dark-mode { #navbar { background-color: black; } }`